# Docker communicate with docker using static IP

Tags: docker

Is that possible to specify a static IP for docker container using docker-compose?

```
eth-java:

    image:
      registry-intl.ap-southeast-1.aliyuncs.com/einnity/coin-ethereum:1.0
    container_name:
      eth-java
    ports:
      - "8002:8198"
    networks:
      my-network:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.1.21
```

And this container will communicate with

eth:

```
image:
  ethereum/client-go
container_name:
  eth
ports:
  - "8545:8545"
  - "30303:30303"
networks:
  my-network:
    ipv4_address: 192.168.1.17
volumes:
  - /storage/eth/rinkeby:/root/.ethereum/rinkeby/
```

and the network settings is

```
networks:
  my-network:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 192.168.1.0/24
```

I type `docker exec -it eth-java /bin/bash`. Then I type `curl` and call RPC on `192.168.1.17:8545`, it doesnt work. If don't hardcode the IP and use the dynamic IP, this will works. I just hate using dynamic IP because everytime when restarting the docker container, another IP will be given and I need to change my DB value every time.

Comment: What is the result when you try to launch your service with the described configuration ?

Comment: I type docker exec -it eth-java /bin/bash.
Then I type curl and call RPC on 192.168.1.17:8545, it doesnt work. If using dynamic IP, it works. I just hate dynamic IP because when restart docker container another IP will be given.

Comment: Please don't add the necessary info in comments, edit your answer instead. And please define "doesn't work" with relevant error log and info.

Comment: Thanks for informing. I have amended accordingly.

Comment: you don't have to use IP. You can use container name in your connection url for db in place of <hostname:port>. Do you have any particular reason not to use them?

Comment: I try your approach. 

If I run

curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_blockNumber","params":[],"id":1}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://172.18.0.2:8545

{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":"0x43b8bc"}

If I run
bash-4.4# curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_blockNumber","params":[],"id":1}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://eth:8545

invalid host specified